How to write JS recursive function to trace sub-graphs, with adjacency list, for a list of initial nodes
Aim:
The aim is to develop a function that quickly traces sub-graphs for a list of nodes, given an existing adjacency list implementation, and returns a list of connected ID's in addition to the original list
Problem
I am finding it hard to understand what to return, and how/where to add the found ID's to the original list. The real issue is deciding:

what the function returns,
how to handle the two cases, recurse further or not

I have a skeleton code, but am starting at it not sure how to finish it off. Can you help please?
Adjacency List Class
Copied from this reference

//------------------------------------------
// Adjaceny List Class
//-------------------------------------------
class Graph {
  
  constructor(){
    this.adjacencyList = new Map();
  }

  addNode(node){
    this.adjacencyList.set(node, new Set());
  }

  addEdge(node1, node2){
    this.adjacencyList.get(node1).set(node2);
  }

  getNeighboors(node){
    return this.adjacencyList.get(node);
  }

  hasEdge(node1, node2){
    return this.adjacencyList.get(node1).has(node2);
  }

}

My half-finished skeleton
can anyone show me what to do with this please so it returns just the list of nodes in the sub-graphs, including the original ID's? Thanks
function traceSubGraph(ID_list, adjacency) {
    let layer_IDs = []
    for (let ID in ID_list) {
        layer_IDs = adjacency.getNeighboors(ID);        
        if (layer_IDs.length) {
            // add new valid nodes to original list of nodes
            ID_list.concat(layer_IDs);
            // keep recursing, but how to add the new values?
            return traceSubGraph(layer_IDs, adjacency)            
        } 
        else {
          // stop recursing, what to do here?
        }
    }
  // what to return? ID_list, but where to add the new found nodes?
}

My Code to Initialise and Drive the Skeleton
function processGraph(graph) {
      // 1. Setup variables and define promotable types
      const prom_types = [
        'incident',
        'task',
        'impact',
        'event',
        'sighting',
      ];
      var returnGraph = {};
      var nodes = graph.nodes;
      var edges = graph.edges;
      var scratch_nodes = [];
      var scratch_edges = [];
      var promotable_nodes = [];
      var prom_IDs = [];
      var collect_IDs = [];
      var promotable_edges = [];
      var adjacency = new Graph();
      // 2. Fill adjacency list with nodes, and get any top level promotables
      for (let node in nodes) {
        adjacency.addNode(node['id']);
        if (node['type'] in prom_types) {
          prom_IDs.push(node.id);
        }
      }  
      // 3. Fill adjacency list with edges
      for (let edge in edges) {
        adjacency.addEdge(edge['source'], edge['target']);
      }
      
      // 4. Now trace out the promotable
      collect_IDs = traceSubGraph(prom_IDs, adjacency);
}

I had worked out that peering through the nodes and edges array was not fast, and then just manually using if/else to go down 3 or 4 layers  was not good either. I then found this adjacency list class online. I have managed to fill it relatively easily, but it is using it to trace the subgraph that has me bedevilled.
Particularly the fact that we are iterating through a list, when we decide whether to recurse or not, makes it seem difficult for me as a noob.
I have tried looking at it for hours, and searching the web for tutorials on recursing, but i am still unsure as to the best approach.

I'm not entirely sure I understand as DSA is not a strong point, but to me it seems like there should be a separate variable from ID_list to add newly-found nodes to, and then that would be returned at the end of the function. The else would be unnecessary; just let the loop continue normally. This would prevent repeating nodes, whereas currently it'd be repeating all existing (and dynamically added) nodes each time it finds an adjacent one (with ID_list being returned as the result at the end of the function).

We need to know the exact format of what is expected as return value. For that purpose, please provide code that initialises a particular graph, and calls your traceSubGraph. Then provide the exact result (in JavaScript notation) that you expect to get from that call.

Note that there is a problem with your addEdge method: .set requires two arguments, but you call it with only one: this.adjacencyList.get(node1).set(node2); Although this does not result in an error, it is counter intuitive that you create inner Map instances that have good keys, but undefined as corresponding values. Is this your implementation, or did you get it as template code?

Hi trincot, I got the adjacency list from here https://dev.to/niemet0502/how-to-implement-a-graph-adjacency-list-and-matrix-in-javascript-2i6g

hi trincot. I have updated the code in the question, so it shows how i fill the adjacency list with id's, and then call the TraceSubGraph() function. I expect back a list of node id's

You didn't copy that implementation correctly. It provides an implementation for unweighted graphs, where it uses new Set instead of new Map, and it provides an implementation for weighted graphs, where it provides the two arguments necessary for a set call. You created a mix of both, ending up with a bad implementation.

Thank you for the added code, but could you please provide code that initialises graph and calls your processGraph function. Then provide the exact result (in JavaScript notation) that you expect to get from that call; I mean literally, for the particular initialisation example of graph.

Wow trincot, that is so true. I had no idea, as JS is not my regular language. I assume using the Map() instead of the Set() is a bad idea. I have updated that bit in my original code and in the question. I generate the nodes and edges arrays in my Python back end, so it is hard to show you that

In your case the graph seems unweighted, so then you would use a Set, and call the .add method in the addEdge method. If you would have a weighted graph, then Map is correct, as you want to associate something to an edge (the weight). But then you should provide that weight in the .set method call. Set is good for registering the fact that there is an edge. Map is good for registering what the weight is for an edge. In your case Set is what you need. Call add not set. (NB: to address someone in comments, just add the at-symbol, not the hyperlink, like @modeller).

hi @trincot, thanks for the suggestions. The data is from cybersecurity, so the nodes look pretty complex. The plan with the adjacency list is just to enter the id fields into it (i.e. ignore the actual node objects, just use id's). You can check out some example data here. My JS file just gets handed the JSON as the graph variable

fix Graph
The nested Map should be a Set because there is no value being associated with the keys. addEdge would break under certain conditions. getNeighboors would return undefined in some cases. addNode wasn't needed for the purposes of this answer -
class Graph {
  constructor() {
    this.t = new Map()
  }
  addEdge(node1, node2) {
    const s = this.t.get(node1)
    if (s == null)
      this.t.set(node1, new Set([node2])) // Set, not Map
    else
      s.add(node2)                        // .add, not .set
  }
  getAdjacencies(node) {
    return this.t.get(node) ?? new Set()
  }
}

Let's construct a concrete graph to use for the rest of our answer. Next time you will provide this in your question -
const g = new Graph()
g.addEdge("A", "B")
g.addEdge("B", "C")
g.addEdge("B", "D")
g.addEdge("D", "E")
g.addEdge("P", "Q")
g.addEdge("Q", "P")
g.addEdge("W", "X")
g.addEdge("W", "Y")
g.addEdge("X", "Z")
g.addEdge("Y", "Z")
g.addEdge("Z", "W")

single entry point
First we will write dir to traverse a single node entry point of our graph. I'm calling it dir because it generates paths to our nodes, much like listing the contents of a directory in a file system -
class Graph {
  //...
  *dir(node, path = Array(), visited = new Set()) {
    yield [...path, node]
    path.push(node)
    visited.add(node)
    for (const adj of this.getAdjacencies(node)) {
      if (!visited.has(adj)) {
        yield* this.dir(adj, path, visited)
      }
    }
    path.pop()
  }
}

Each path is a sequence of nodes, we can visualize them as familiar string paths by joining the segments with a separator, / -
for (const path of g.dir("A")) {
  console.log(path.join("/"))
}

A
A/B
A/B/C
A/B/D
A/B/D/E

But more importantly we can manipulate these paths to extract the data we care about for a particular traversal. In this example, we find all unique nodes in the subgraph of A by selecting the basename of each path -
for (const path of g.dir("A")) {
  console.log(path.at(-1)) // basename
}

A
B
C
D
E

multiple entry points
Currently dir only accepts a single node entry point. To complete the rest of your problem, we can write dirs that accepts an array of nodes representing multiple entry points to the graph -
class Graph {
  //...
  *dirs(nodes) {
    for (const node of nodes) {
      yield* this.dir(node)
    }
  }
}

Now we call dirs with an array of entry points -
for (const path of g.dirs(["B", "W"])) {
  console.log(path.join("/"))
}

B
B/C
B/D
B/D/E
W
W/X
W/X/Z
W/Y

Or again using path manipulation to collect all nodes reachable from B and W -
console.log(Array.from(g.dirs(["B", "W"]), path => path.at(-1)))

[ "B", "C", "D", "E", "W", "X", "Z", "Y" ]

remarks
Hopefully you can see writing dir in this way means we offload the hard choices to users of our program. Instead of trying to predict the needs of the traversal consumer, dir produces a path to each reachable node. Now each program that needs to traverse the graph can make distinct choices based on that program's unique context.
And maybe you noticed in the dirs example that we only produced one path to Z even though multiple paths existed. This is a concern I will address in my next answer to this question.
demo


class Graph {
  constructor() {
    this.t = new Map()
  }
  addEdge(node1, node2) {
    const s = this.t.get(node1)
    if (s == null) this.t.set(node1, new Set([node2]))
    else s.add(node2)
  }
  getAdjacencies(node) {
    return this.t.get(node) ?? new Set()
  }
  *dir(node, path = Array(), visited = new Set()) {
    yield [...path, node]
    path.push(node)
    visited.add(node)
    for (const adj of this.getAdjacencies(node)) {
      if (!visited.has(adj)) {
        yield* this.dir(adj, path, visited)
      }
    }
    path.pop()
  }
  *dirs(nodes) {
    for (const node of nodes) {
      yield* this.dir(node)
    }
  }
}

const g = new Graph()
g.addEdge("A", "B"); g.addEdge("B", "C"); g.addEdge("B", "D"); g.addEdge("D", "E"); g.addEdge("P", "Q"); g.addEdge("Q", "P"); g.addEdge("W", "X"); g.addEdge("W", "Y"); g.addEdge("X", "Z"); g.addEdge("Y", "Z"); g.addEdge("Z", "W")

for (const path of g.dir("A")) {
  console.log(path.join("/"))
}

for (const path of g.dir("A")) {
  console.log(path.at(-1))
}

for (const path of g.dirs(["B", "W"])) {
  console.log(path.join("/"))
}

console.log(Array.from(g.dirs(["B", "W"]), path => path.at(-1)))
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0 }



typescript
type Node = string

class Graph {
  t: Map<Node, Set<Node>>
  constructor() {
    this.t = new Map()
  }
  addEdge(node1: Node, node2: Node): void {
    const s = this.t.get(node1)
    if (s == null) this.t.set(node1, new Set([node2]))
    else s.add(node2)
  }
  getAdjacencies(node: Node): Set<Node> {
    return this.t.get(node) ?? new Set()
  }
  *dir(
    node: Node,
    path = Array<Node>(),
    visited = new Set<Node>(),
  ): Generator<Node[]> {
    yield [...path, node]
    path.push(node)
    visited.add(node)
    for (const adj of this.getAdjacencies(node)) {
      if (!visited.has(adj)) {
        yield* this.dir(adj, path, visited)
      }
    }
    path.pop()
  }
  *dirs(nodes: Node[]): Generator<Node[]> {
    for (const node of nodes) {
      yield* this.dir(node)
    }
  }
}


there was a sort of sixth sense as I was writing this that the question was spoiled from the beginning. the Graph in your question is very different from the source graph you just linked. I'll leave this answer to give you a chance to read it. If you find it helpful let me know, otherwise I will delete it.

wow thats some amazing code mulan. Thanks so much for that. As you can tell i am a noob and a bit lost

I'm not that good at JS mulan, I am not even sure about some of that dir() function code you used. So can dir be made general purpose for any path, as you show? wow, mind blowing

dir is a function we wrote here in the post, defined inside your Graph class so that you can traverse our graphs objects (g) using a common file/directory-like system. We could call the function paths or any other name we pick. As for making the traversal function more general purpose, I demonstrated such a technique in this recent Q&A.

I'll try to provide another answer to this question using the updated Graph data structure from the post. I might not get around to it until this weekend.

wow @mulan mulan, I keep staring at your code, and am just blown away by it. I will definitely adopt it, but I note that it does not actually solve the problem, as a path is not a sub-graph. It does create useful capabilities, but now i have to work out how to create each sub-graph from your list of paths. I am sure i can work out how to do that, fingers crossed

thank you, I'm glad you are finding it helpful :D to solve your "actual" problem, do you think it might be best to open a new question with the exact data structure you are using and the exact output you are expecting?

hey @mulan I have now successfully implemented your code, inside my own. Your solution made it tremendously easy to get the array (set) of sub-nodes, based on a list of one or more input nodes without any repeats. It was so brilliant, I just start a new adjacency list, add all of the edges to it, and then run your fourth console.log statement in your code snippet, by sending it a list of my top-level nodes and it gathers the array of connected, unique ID's in one command. Brilliant stuff, thank you!!

it's always nice to hear back, especially when it's good news like this. thanks for taking the time to share your success with me <3
